# csv.reader parsing files incorrectly

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab delimited file with 6 identical lines (test file can be downloaded [here](https://copy.com/IX46qDCZhqNu)):

```
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
2635243 Uckfield    Uckfield    "kfijld,Ъкфийлд 50.96948    0.09589 P   PPL GB      ENG E2  21UH        15716       19  Europe/London   2010-05-24
```

When I try to read them with csv.reader I only get 3 lines correctly parsed:

```
>>> import csv    
>>> len(list(csv.reader(open('test.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')))
3
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Further testing indicates that only the even lines (first, third and fifth) are being parsed. May be some EOL issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable quoting and it will work:

```
len(list(csv.reader(open('test.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)))
```

will return *6*

The problem here is that CSV parser takes new line character `\n` as part of the field, because you have the default quotes `"` in each line before `kfijld`